# How can I convert my double value called `q`and display the values before/after the decimal place?

Tags: java

How can I convert my double value called `q` and display the values before/after the decimal place? On my attempt below, I have converted the value to a string but the rest I'm not sure about.

```
double q = 19.0/2.0; 

//convert double to string using valueOf() method
String str = String.valueOf(q);  

//displaying output string after conversion
System.out.println("My String is: "+str);
```

Comment: Yes I have corrected the original post. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: If you have it as `String`, you can `split` it by a dot and then you have the part before the dot separated from the decimal places. Is that what you want?

Comment: `String str = String.format("%6.2f", q); System.out.printf("My String is: %6.3f!%n", q);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to convert the double to ? 
In any case, if you convert it to String then for printing the digits before and after the decimal :

```
    System.out.println("Before decimal : " + str.split("\\.")[0]);
    System.out.println("After decimal : " + str.split("\\.")[1]);
```